# Redirect Rules for .htaccess File

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What will be the code for these redirects in the .htaccess file?

www.site.com/books/ =====> www.site.com/movies/

www.site.com/books/title/ =====> www.site.com/movies/title.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it as 301 redirect (and assuming your htaccess file is in the root folder), then these rules will do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^books/$ http://www.example.com/movies/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^books/title/$ http://www.example.com/movies/title.html [R=301,L]
```

Replace example.com with your domain name.
Search here in S.O. also. There are countless posts on how to do these redirections.

**Edit**: For dynamic titles the second rule becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([^.]+)/$ http://www.example.com/movies/$1\.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: title in the second rule is dynamic. Will your code work with that?

Comment: @user3180358 i have edited my answer with dynamic titles

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!